# Hyperledger Fabric transaction proposal and commit conflict

Tags: process, hyperledger-fabric, peer

This is a general question which is boggling me from long time.

In the process between endorsing peer responding to transaction proposals( assume N) from client to sending the R/W set to orderer what if there is another transaction proposal( Assume M) being proposed which has changes for the values in 'N' ? how is this handled, because in this case the version of commit will be different for N and M, and hence M will fail.
If you say that it's like simulation from endorser or commit from peer which comes first wins. Is this fair ?

How do you explain ?

Answer (score 0):

As you state above, conflicts are not detected during simulation; they are handled as part of validation and commit.  All transactions are ordered, so the first one added to a block by the orderer will be processed as valid and committed.  Subsequent transactions will be marked as invalid due to conflict in the persisted block(s) and the state change will be ignored.

Comment: isn't the transaction is lost when it is made invalid ?  this is not always feasible

Comment: it's not lost ... it's still in the block and the client can check on the status and modify and resend if required

Comment: when the endorser R/W set does not match with state( of M ), how will it go further and create block ? transactions are yet to go into block.